# what is the relationship between Application server and JVM?

Tags: java, application-server

A quick question that come up to my mind and I thought to post it here to clarify my inner concerns.

What is the relationship between APP server (i.e. JBoss, WebLogic etc) and JVM?

Where is APP server located; does it run within JVM?

Many Thanks!

Comment: yes, the app server runs on a JVM

Comment: @Eduardo - Ok thanks! any reference that you can redirect me to!

Comment: App server is a java program so it runs in JVM

Comment: Go to the website of any of those app servers, download the source code, and you will see that it is Java.

Comment: @Eduardo + AmitD - Thanks a lot to both, really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `Java application servers`, the server behaves like an extended virtual machine for running applications, transparently handling connections to the database on one side, and, often, connections to the Web client on the other.

- [Application Server vs JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server)

Comment: So the app server doesn't run within JVM; it rather runs on top of JVM?

Answer (score 1):

JVM is java run time platform on top of which every java applications runs, it can be a simple stand alone application, an applet or web application. It provides support for execution life cycle of an application. In other words any thing written in Java runs on top of this platform.

An application server is a container in which a specialized Java application, a web application, runs. It provides support for web application life cycle like Servlet and JSP life cycle management, JNDI, JMS and other supports. Actually, an application server is  generally a java application running on top of JVM.

Answer (score 0):

APP server developed in respect to J2EE specifications using J2SE and J2EE APIs. Yes, as APP developed in java you have to execute it on top of JVM it self. You can treat running APP as executing a bigggg java class